# Getting the value of Pointer Class in Parse Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Here's my code:

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("_User");
query.include("Position");

query.getInBackground(user.getObjectId(), new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject user, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      ParseObject p = (ParseObject) user.get("Position");

      Log.d("POSITION", p.getString("name"));
    } else {
      Log.d("Position", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
});
```

The User class has a column "pointerId" that points to the Position class. In my code, p.getString("name") returns null everytime. I hope you can help. tia.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Here the user is already given and you want to fetch the Position class:

```
String positionId = user.getParseObject("positionId").getObjectId();

ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Position");

query.getInBackground(positionId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    ...
}
```

I hope this helps someone in the future. :)